# Is it possible to to cache a response using cache-control in spring boot controller?

Tags: angularjs, http, caching, spring-boot, cache-control

My requirement is to reuse some meta-data in browser level rather than requesting every time from server. My rest end point has written using spring boot and i have added Cache-control and max-age headers to my response. I had set max-age to 10 seconds. As per my understanding we can do this for fixed assets like css and js files. Is it possible to do with a object(response).

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/retrieve/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Course> getCourses(@PathVariable String name) {
    Course course = new Course();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    try {
        System.out.println("Call is here.");
        course = courseService.getCourse(name);
        headers.add("Cache-control", "private");
        headers.add("max-age", "10");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(course, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(course, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

But in front end level the request is still going in to server and serves with a new response. I'm using angualr as my client side framework.I want to clear the response data after completing the max-age value that has mentioned in the response header.

this is the related angular component.

```
app.component('searchCourseComponent', {
bindings: {
    name: '<',
},
templateUrl: 'components/course-search/course-search.component.html',
controller: function (localStorageService, CourseService) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.searchCourseByName = function (name) {

        if (localStorageService.isSupported) {
            console.log("localStrage is supporting in this browser");
            var course = CourseService.searchCourse(name).then(function (response) {
                localStorageService.set("course", response.data);
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log("Local storage is not supporting");
        }
    };
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

You can use local storage service in angularJs. 
For this include the below in `index.html`

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-local-storage/0.7.1/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>
```

Inject `LocalStorageModule` into app.module

```
angular.module('appName', ['LocalStorageModule'])
```

and while using in controller inject `localStorageService` into controller and set value you want to store into local storage.

For example: `localStorageService.set("nameForStoringData",dataToBeSet);`

Comment: I did the same thing in my angular application. But it can save the value in the browser. But if i send a request again it goes to server. It will not using the cache copy. That is the problem.

Comment: Can you share your angular code for better understanding

Comment: check with condition `var course = localStorageService.get(course); if(course == undefined && course == null){ //then only hit the service}` your if condition is wrong, As localStorage is supported by all browsers. and don't forget to clear local storage after terminating the application

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angualr $http cache for this. It will not send same request again.

```
    $http({
            method: type,
            url: url,
            params: params,
            cache: true,
            responseType: responseType
        }).then(function (response) {
           // success response
        }, function (response) {
          // when something went wrong
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way, create `servlet filter` and add headers to response what ever you need.

First create this configuration **class**:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureAfter;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableCaching 
public class CacheConfiguration { 

}
```

and this servlet filter:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; 

public class CachingHttpHeadersFilter implements Filter {

    // We consider the last modified date is the start up time of the server
    private final static long LAST_MODIFIED = System.currentTimeMillis();

    private long CACHE_TIME_TO_LIVE = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1461L);

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        CACHE_TIME_TO_LIVE = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(365); //365 days
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // Nothing to destroy
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=" + CACHE_TIME_TO_LIVE + ", public");
        httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "cache");

        // Setting Expires header, for proxy caching
        httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", CACHE_TIME_TO_LIVE + System.currentTimeMillis());

        // Setting the Last-Modified header, for browser caching
        httpResponse.setDateHeader("Last-Modified", LAST_MODIFIED);

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

and register this filter and add urlPatterns you need :

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean cachingHttpHeadersFilter() throws IOException {
    log.info("Registering Caching HTTP Headers Filter");

    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(new CachingHttpHeadersFilter());
    registration.setDispatcherTypes(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ASYNC));
    registration.setName("cachingHttpHeadersFilter");
    List<String> urlPatterns = new ArrayList<>();
    urlPatterns.add("/asset*");
    registration.setUrlPatterns(urlPatterns);
    return registration;
}
```

registered filter adds cache-control header to `http requests` association with `/asset*` 
.